# What is the general expression for the $n^{th}$ term of these sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence $\{ M \}$ such that $M_n = \frac{n!}{2^{\left( \frac{1}{4} \right )\left( 2n+1+(-1)^{n+1} \right )}} = (n!)2^{-\left( \frac{1}{4} \right )\left( 2n+1+(-1)^{n+1} \right )}$. In other words, $\{M\} = \big\{ 1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2}, 6, 15, 90, 315, 2520, 11340, 113400,...\big\}$ (we will count all of these sequences beginning with the $0^{th}$ index).

Now, suppose I have $2$ sequences $P$ and $Q$ which seem to be transformed versions of $M$. Here are the first few terms of each:

$\{P\} = \big\{1, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{3}{2}, -6, 15, 0, -315, 2520, -11340, 0, ...\big\} $

$\{Q\} = \big\{0, \frac{1}{2}, -1, \frac{3}{2}, 0, -15, 90, -315, 0, 11340, -113400, ...\big\} $

It seems like each term in $P$ and $Q$ are simply terms in $M$ multiplied with either $1$, $-1$ or $0$. I have created $2$ new sequences $\{s_p\}$ and $\{s_q\}$ such that $M_n(s_p)_n = P_n$ and $M_n(s_q)_n = Q_n$ as follows:

$\{s_p\}=\big\{ 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, ...\big\} $

$\{s_q\}=\big\{0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, ...\big\}  $

My ultimate question is: How do I find the $n^{th}$ term of $P$ and $Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to find an explicit formula for $s_p$ and one for $s_q$.
It looks like they are both $8$-periodic, with the pattern $1$, $-1$, $1$, $0$, $-1$, $1$, $-1$, $0$ repeating ($s_q$ is a shifted version of $s_p$ which can be deduced from the formula of $s_p$).
Try shifting this one :
$$u_n = \rm{i} \frac{(-1 - \rm{i})^n - (-1 + \rm{i})^n}{2^{\lfloor 1 + n/2 \rfloor}}$$
and proving that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ is indeed the $8$-periodic sequence with first eight terms $0$, $1$, $-1$, $1$, $0$, $-1$, $1$, $-1$.

Comment: Following your formula, we get that $u_n = s_q$, and finding an equation for $s_p$ is easy from here. However, is there any way to write this equation without the use of floor division? Secondly, can you explain how you even got this in the first place?

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple way of removing the floor. You can get the formula by finding a sequence which *sign* is that of $s_q$ (irrespective of the absolute value) with a recursive formula of order 2. Then, you just divide by the absolute value to only get the signs.